# how to find if the attr rel contains portion of a text

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
   if($(this).find('a').attr('rel') =="#videopicturevideo_picture_123"){
    alert("contains video");
    }
```

Instead of == is there a way to use contains ("video) for the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `indexOf` like below,

```
if($(this).find('a').attr('rel').indexOf('video') >= 0) {
   alert("contains video");
}
```

or use attribute [**contains**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector like below,

```
if($(this).find('a[rel*=video]').length) {
   alert("contains video");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you you can use a regex:

```
if($(this).find('a').attr('rel').match(/.*video.*/)){
    alert("contains video");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a_with_video = $("a[rel^='#videopicturevideo_picture_123']");
```